# How to load a players name in URL via API call - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I want to display a players Gamer-tag in my URL. The trouble I'am having is I don't know how to request a gamer-tag in the search box because I'am requesting the gamer tag via a API call.

Right now this is how I call the route:

```
    Route::post('/Player/Stats', [
        'as' => 'player-stats',
        'uses' => 'StatsController@index'
    ]);
```

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// this is how I set up my search box for home page
<form action="{{ route('player-stats') }}" method="POST">
      {!! csrf_field() !!}
      <input type="text" name="gamertag" id="gamertag" class="form-control" title="Gamer-tag" style="width:40%" required>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Find</button>
 </form>
```

This is how it looks:
[image: My URL for a players name]

What I want it to be is like this:

```
Route::post('/Player/Stats/{gamertag}', [
   'as' => 'player-stats',
   'uses' => 'StatsController@index'
]);
```

[image: How I want the URl to look like]

I cant do this in my form action:

> action="{{ route('player-stats', $gamertag }}"

because $gamertag is not stored anywhere

Comment: Make this optional {gamertag?} And just update url by js. Its not solution just another way

Comment: further explaining would be handy mate, can you explain more what do you want and what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to display a players name (Gamertag) in the URl when a type a players gamer-tag in the search box

Answer (score 1):

The trouble here is less to do with PHP and more to do with JavaScript.

You'll need to use the `history API` provided by `HTML5`. This will allow you to push/pop `states` off of the history. What this ultimately means is that you'll be able to modify the URL address.

Let's take a look at what that entails. We'll make an assumption that you are returning a JSON object from a controller via an ajax request fired from a form submit on a search input.

```
public function MyController(Request $request){
    $model = Models::where('key', $request->get('value'))->first();
    return response()->json($model);
}
```

Of course, the associated Ajax and jQuery.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         //props
         dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response){
        //magic
        history.pushState(null, null, 'Player/stats/'+response.gamertag);
    });
});
```

What the `history.pushState` will do here is modify the URL and change it according to the 3rd argument of the `pushState` function. **Note** you can't change the domain name, so the URL is only manipulated after the FQDN, such as `http://example.com`. However you do need to provide the `full path` after the FQDN as the 3rd argument.

The first argument of `.pushState()` is `data`. You could then store your `ajax response object` inside of this **state**. When the user clicks `back` in their browser the `popState` event fires, allowing us to access the state. Let's have a look at that.

```
$(window).on('popState', function(e){
    //e.state contains the data, otherwise e.originalEvent.state will.
});
```

The most common use case of this is to store the `ajax response` inside of the state, so when clicking back in the browser, you just re-perform whatever actions you did in the `.done()` response. Let's see that

```
var $results_container = $('.results-container');
function showResults(response){
    //parsing and logic here to handle the ajax response and "Show Results"

    $results_container.empty();
    $.each(response.row, function(i, row){
        $results_container.append(row);
    });
}
```

Now inside of your `ajax .done()` function, you can just pass the response to our function.

```
.done(function(response){
    showResults(response);
});
```

However, we can also do the same in our `popState()` function now.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e){
    showResults(e.state);

    //or maybe it's showResults(e.originalEvent.state)
    //honestly can't remember
});
```

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.